# Product Images not showing after hosting moved

Tags: php, opencart

I have no product image show After backup all my opencart files including DB, then I moved it to another hosting. when I check html structure on browser, value of src attribute on tag image is empty. would be nice if someone can help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your backup didn't include product images, just the database. Here someone had similar problem:

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=25856

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for fast response and sorry for my late reply. its awsome...